# Convert long to wide format r

Tags: r, format, reshape

I am trying to convert a dataset from long to wide format in R.

In particular, my dataset looks like this:

```
[1] "progNum"               "SbjID"                 "age"                  
 [4] "gender"                "ethnicity"             "skinTone"             
 [7] "sbjName"               "HR_powerBased"         "HR_coherenceBased"    
[10] "maxIdx_filt"           "smoothy"               "s2nrat"               
[13] "nFrames"               "vidDuration"           "frameRate"            
[16] "threshold"             "warningMess"           "nFacesDetected"       
[19] "enoughPointsVisible"   "luminance"             "flag"                 
[22] "nPeaksAboveThreshold"  "maxFreqDiff"           "task"                 
[25] "trial"                 "allTaskNames"          "allTaskSecs"          
[28] "Names"                 "Beats"                 "Distance"             
[31] "rPPGEstimatedBeats"    "estimatedBeatsSmoothy" "HR_ECG"               
[34] "Name"                  "participant"
```

I want to keep all the variables but I need to separate "HR_ECG" and "smoothy" by "Distance" and "trial".

Distance can be either 0 or 1
trial has 4 levels: 25, 35, 45, 100

That is, in the end, I need a dataframe that looks like this:

progNum, sbjID, age [...]  HR_ECG_close_25, HR_ECG_close_35, HR_ECG_close_45, HR_ECG_close_100, HR_ECG_far_25, HR_ECG_far_35, HR_ECG_far_45, HR_ECG_far_100
And the same for smoothy:
smoothy_close_25, smoothy_close_35, smoothy_close_45, smoothy_close_100, smoothy_far_25, smoothy_far_35, smoothy_far_45, smoothy_far_100

I hope this makes sense, thank you so much in advance

EDITED BASED ON COMMENT - Reproducible dataset:

```
structure(list(progNum = c(12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30), SbjID = c(456465465, 456465465, 
456465465, 456465465, 456465465, 456465465, 456465465, 456465465, 
64846846846, 64846846846, 64846846846, 64846846846, 64846846846, 
64846846846, 64846846846, 64846846846), age = c("19", "19", "19", 
"19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
"19", "19"), gender = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male"), smoothy = c(77.9221097737332, 78.5599580813492, 
75.8424141201793, 78.6216428610833, 81.4167032250805, 76.9509617898643, 
83.5251636058245, 76.5866099353627, 86.6511432503543, 86.3901538762173, 
84.6411757168127, 87.0600014771307, 85.3731055604431, 81.5935438011446, 
83.38581442316, 85.2329422916703), nFrames = c(599, 838, 1078, 
2397, 599, 839, 1078, 2397, 599, 838, 1079, 2397, 598, 839, 1079, 
2396), vidDuration = c(24.984, 34.952, 44.962, 99.975, 24.984, 
34.994, 44.962, 99.975, 24.984, 34.952, 45.004, 99.975, 24.942, 
34.994, 45.004, 99.934), frameRate = c(23.9353186039065, 23.947127489128, 
23.9535607846626, 23.9659914978745, 23.9353186039065, 23.9469623364005, 
23.9535607846626, 23.9659914978745, 23.9353186039065, 23.947127489128, 
23.9534263621012, 23.9659914978745, 23.935530430599, 23.9469623364005, 
23.9534263621012, 23.9658174395101), trial = c(25, 35, 45, 100, 
25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100), allTaskSecs = c("25", 
"35", "45", "100", "25_Far", "35_Far", "45_Far", "100_Far", "25", 
"35", "45", "100", "25_Far", "35_Far", "45_Far", "100_Far"), 
    Names = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2"), Beats = c(33, 
    46, 62, 130, 31, 47, 58, 132, 36, 48, 63, 144, 37, 52, 65, 
    146), Distance = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), rPPGEstimatedBeats = c(32.4675457390555, 45.8266422141203, 
    56.8818105901344, 131.036071435139, 33.9236263437836, 44.8880610440875, 
    62.6438727043684, 127.644349892271, 36.1046430209809, 50.3942564277934, 
    63.4808817876095, 145.100002461884, 35.5721273168513, 47.596233884001, 
    62.53936081737, 142.05490381945), estimatedBeatsSmoothy = c(32.4675457390555, 
    45.8266422141203, 56.8818105901344, 131.036071435139, 33.9236263437836, 
    44.8880610440875, 62.6438727043684, 127.644349892271, 36.1046430209809, 
    50.3942564277934, 63.4808817876095, 145.100002461884, 35.5721273168513, 
    47.596233884001, 62.53936081737, 142.05490381945), HR_ECG = c(79.2, 
    78.8571428571429, 82.6666666666667, 78, 74.4, 80.5714285714286, 
    77.3333333333333, 79.2, 86.4, 82.2857142857143, 84, 86.4, 
    88.8, 89.1428571428571, 86.6666666666667, 87.6), Name = c("A1", 
    "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", 
    "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: Provide reproducible data please: `dput(myData)`

Comment: Great, now what is the expected output for this example dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider` from the `tidyr` package:

```r
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Distance = if_else(Distance == 0, "close", "far")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("Distance", "trial"), values_from = c("HR_ECG", "smoothy"))
```

---

The problem with your data is that the values in the other columns are not unique for each SbjID, therefore you will find many NAs in the pivoted data in the newly created columns. I suppose you may want to `select` which columns to keep before pivoting, or you may want to pivot more columns.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly. And you are right, I had to select the columns to keep as I didn't need all of them anyways. 
Thank you again